# Reasons to use a voltage divider and regulator?

Tags: voltage-regulator, voltage-divider

If I have a circuit that requires 2V, I can use a voltage divider to get me the 2V from the 3V battery. I have been told that it is a good idea then to run that through a 2V regulator. This seems like overkill to me.

Are there any advantages to this? Is it better to drop the divider and just use the regulator?

Comment: Your circuit needs a *current* too at the specific voltage.

Comment: Do you need power at 2V, or do you need a reference voltage of 2V?

Comment: @JRE A reference. Everything else would be powered off the battery.

Comment: If the dropped power was relatively high, you may well consider putting your supply through a series resistor and into a 2V regulator. That way the regulator isn't dissipating all of the dropped power, which may be valuable in keeping its temperature down and its output less variable across all loads. But I wouldn't normally do that when dropping such a small voltage as 1V. Tell us more about your application, load current and behaviour etc.

Comment: Sketch your circuit using the schematic editor (edit your question and press CTRL M)  You might be able to get away without a regulator, you might not.

Comment: Unfortunately you omit a crucial parameter, how much **current** is needed at that 2 V ? If it is 1 uA, a couple of resistors might do. For 10 mA or more, a regulator is better. Also, how **stable** does that 2 V need to be ? Is it OK if it becomes 1.8 V or 2.2 V ? I can think of 10 different circuits to make 2 V out of 3 V, which one is best depends on what you need. Your needs are still unclear (yes, specifying circuit requirements is difficult, it takes experience).

Comment: @FakeMoustache (and @JRE) Thanks! That's going to be it! I am going to try and design a small micro-controller based system to detect if a surface get's moved. I don't have a circuit diagram yet, I am just thinking about what I need and the discussion about the regulator etc. came up in discussion, but there will be a micro-controller etc., so it will require (I am sure) a higher amount of current. Thanks!

Comment: The thing with a voltage divider is: the output voltage will only be as accurate as the resistors are (a few %) and the output voltage will depend on the input voltage (batteries discharge and their voltage changes). A regulator or proper reference voltage source are much more accurate.

Comment: But you wrote: *Everything else would be powered off the battery* I interpret that as *running of the 3 V*. You should start on a schematic already even if it is just as empty blocks because that will show what you need and what it is connected to.

Comment: @0x6d64 And there you make an **assumption** about which nothing has been stated yet. Who said the 2 V needs to be accurate ? Maybe it is for battery level detection and then you do want to use a resistive divider. At OP: see how easily people point you in a direction based on assumptions (and not facts). That is why it is so important to show the complete picture.

Comment: @FakeMoustache I would like the reference to be stable.  But then this may not be be as important as I think. I think the best thing to do would be to get a schematic sorted and then come back to this question with any issues. Thanks to everyone for the help so far! It has got me thinking about a few things.

Comment: @o.fithcheallaigh, when you say "reference" we think you mean a voltage level that might be compared with other voltages to measure those other voltages. A reference generally doesn't need to provide any power to the circuit it's connected to. But in another comment you say " there will be a micro-controller etc., so it will require (I am sure) a higher amount of current." If your 2 V will provide power to these components you should not be talking about a reference, you should be talking about a "power supply".

Answer (score 3):

In general, you have got three different opportunities to reduce your battery voltage from 3V to 2V. Each opportunity has got its own advantages and disadvantages and should (must) be used for different applications:

1. Voltage divider:
   Voltage divider are used for applications which don't need any current but a common reference voltage. You can't drive a huge current because this would change your divide proportion. Mention that V_out depends on V_in. So if your battery voltage goes down, your reference voltage goes down too.

Typically applications: OP gain resistors, Voltage for feedback inputs

2. Reference diode:
   Reference diodes are used for applications which don't need any current but a very exact reference voltage. In this case your reference voltage doesn't depend on V_in.

Typically application: ADC reference, OP circuits

3. Voltage regulator:
   Voltage regulators are used for applications which need more or less load current. In this case your voltage doesn't depend on V_in. There are two different types of voltage regulators. On the one hand you can easily use a linear regulator or on the other hand you can use a clocked buck down regulator for high efficiency.

Typically applications: Supply voltage for circuit parts

Hope this help you!

Answer (score 1):

A voltage divider looks like this (roughly):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftgwTB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The problem is that Vout will change if Vin changes, but also if Z_load changes:

\$ V_{out} = V_{in}\frac{R_2||Z_{load}}{R_1+(R_2||Z_{load})} \$

For \$Z_{load} \gg R_2\$, \$V_{out} = V_{in}\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}\$, and you can use a voltage divider.  If \$Z_{load} \approx R_2\$, then you have to use the whole expression.  If \$Z_{load}\$ is unknown, or changes, then you run into more problems.