# I'm using 12volt to Arduino UNO, but I have questions

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, power-supply, voltage, power

I have this project where I use a stepper motor controlled with an Arduino and bluetooth module.

It says that I need 12volts to power the Arduino to control the stepper motor, my question is if I need a voltage divider to the bluetooth module (says 3.3 to 6 Volt)  to not burn it.

Comment: While this doesn't answer your real question "how to arrange power supply around Arduino?", a voltage divider almost never makes a good power supply.  Thorough discussion on that [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/106718/7036) and [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/258223/7036).

Comment: 1) The Arduino UNO does not provide 12V. It cannot directly power a 12V motor. 2) You didn't explain what connection you are asking about with the Bluetooth module, you just said "to the [module]". To power it? To communicate with it? 3) Note that if you're powering the UNO via the VIN pin with 12V, it may shorten it's life span (from excessive heat). I suggest staying under 10V on the VIN pin. 4) As a beginner, you must learn provide as many details as possible, because otherwise people must guess what is going on with your setup. This includes providing schematics.

Answer (score 2):

A voltage divider is usually completely unsuitable for powering sensors or modules as they draw too much (and variable) current.

If you are powering your Arduino from 12 volts, and using this same power supply to run your stepper motor you should be ok.

The Arduino has two on board power regulators, one for the Arduino MCU running at 5V and another that provides 3.3V for peripheral use. If your BLE module works at 5V then simply hook it to the Arduino VCC.

There is plenty of [documentation](https://www.circuito.io/blog/arduino-uno-pinout/) on the Arduino variants, I've pointed to only one here.

[image]

Before you go further you should at the very minimum try to understand the configuration of the Arduino you are using. If you can understand the schematic, that is helpful too.